# when my app is closed i want to trigger a phone incoming call to show a notification message? It's possible to do flutter without using native code?

Tags: flutter, dart

Now I was doing like true caller based app I have use phone-status package to redirect in my phone incoming call and to get incoming call number post my local api to get name to display my screen to use local notification package to show notification in screen but I have facing problem when my app is closed the follow steps is not work

i was tried to show notification when the incoming call come but it's don't run in while app is closed?
i was using Phone_status, local_notification and flutter background service

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.